# Is the pushout of essential monomorphism an essential monomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

If we have two essential monomorphisms $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and $g\colon A\longrightarrow C$ with pushout $\alpha\colon B\longrightarrow P$ and $\beta \colon C\longrightarrow P$ with $\alpha f=\beta g$. Is true that $\alpha f$ is an essential monomorphism?

Commonly the notion of essentiality is studied from the perspective of the subobjects, here I have the question from the perspective of supraobjects.

In the case of module theory the pushout corresponds to the internal sum, can we say anything in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In the category of abelian groups, take $f$ and $g$ both to be the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by $2$. Then the pushout $P$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and $\alpha f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not an essential monomorphism, as the intersection of its image with the summand $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.